# Some efficient way to implement insertion and lookup for this kind of map?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I am wondering how to implement the following efficiently:

A hash map that maps a subset of a set to another set. For example, for the set {1, 2}, then the insertions to the map are {1} -> {100}, {2} -> {100}, {1, 2}-> {100} (the empty set is not considered)

While the insertion complexity is almost 2^|X|, which is the number of subset of powerset of X to insert ( |X| stands for the cardinality of the set X).

How to use Haskell map and set to efficiently implement this? Or construct new data structures and schemes based on Haskell existing map and set?

---

Be more specific

1. Insertions: get subset of a set, insert the mapping from each subset to the value set, if the key is already there, union the result.
2. Lookups: given a set A, first get all the subset of A, then for each subset, look it up in the SetMap, then union the results as the return value.

For example:
If first insert `{1, 2} -> {100}` in a empty map `M`,

1. Insertions:

   - then insertions are: `({1}, {100}), ({2}, {100}), ({1,2}, {100}).`
   - if further to insert `{2,3}->{200}`, then for each subset of `{2, 3}`, if there is already key in `M`, union {200} with that value. If not, just set the value as `{200}`. So, the  map will now look like `({1}, {100}),({2}, {100,200}), ({3},{200}), ({1,2}, {100}), ({2,3}, {200})`
2. Lookups:

   - lookup `{2,3}`, works almost like insertions: first get subsets of `{2,3}`, which are `{2},{3}, {2,3}`, for each of those subsets, look it up in the `M`, union all the results, which are `{100, 200} union {200} union {200} = {100,200}` (after two steps in 1.). (union empty set if the key not found)

Also the Aside problem: how to efficiently implement generating powerset!

Comment: What happens when the client inserts first {1, 2} → {100}, then {2, 3} → {200}?

Comment: @larsmans Oh, the core of the problem is in the domain of the map, which is all the subset of a powerset, which will all map to the same value set.

Comment: Based on a gut feeling: when I read the keywords map, hash, efficient -> I think bloom filters could play a role in the desired solution. Is that from some sort of homework?

Comment: @JFritsch Nope, and the semester just starts, no homework yet:), It is just a bit from personal interested project, and looking at "bloom filters" in the wiki...

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification.  This is interesting, there's some cool structure in here.  Let me think about it :-)

Comment: @luqui Thank you for encouraging me to clarify the problem. I didn't think hard enough to ask the question before your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shameless rip-off of @Daniel Wagner's solution with the counting set implementation I suggested:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Control.Arrow ( (&&&) )

type SetMap k v = (Map k (Map v Int), Map (Set k) (Set v))

emptySM :: SetMap k v
emptySM = (M.empty, M.empty)

insertSM :: (Ord k, Ord v) => Set k -> Set v -> SetMap k v -> SetMap k v
insertSM keys values setMap = (keyMap', keySetMap') where
  (keyMap, keySetMap) = deleteSM keys setMap
  keyMap' = M.unionWith (M.unionWith (+)) keyMap newKeyMap where
    newKeyMap = fromSet keys . fromSet values $ 1
  keySetMap' = M.insert keys values keySetMap

lookupSM :: (Ord k, Ord v) => Set k -> SetMap k v -> Set v
lookupSM keys (keyMap, _) = S.fromList $ S.toList keys >>= flatLookup keyMap where
  flatLookup m k = maybe [] M.keys . M.lookup k $ m

deleteSM :: (Ord k, Ord v) => Set k -> SetMap k v -> SetMap k v
deleteSM keys setMap@(keyMap, keySetMap) = maybe setMap setMap' valuesIndex where
  setMap' = keyMap' &&& keySetMap'
  valuesIndex = M.lookupIndex keys keySetMap
  keyMap' i = differenceUntil (differenceUntil (-) (==0)) M.null keyMap oldKeyMap where
    values = snd . M.elemAt i $ keySetMap
    oldKeyMap = fromSet keys . fromSet values $ 1
  keySetMap' i = M.deleteAt i keySetMap

differenceUntil :: Ord k => (a -> b -> a) -> (a -> Bool) -> Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k a
differenceUntil f p = M.differenceWith $
  \a b -> let a' = f a b in if p a' then Nothing else Just a'

fromSet :: Ord k => Set k -> v -> Map k v
fromSet s v = M.fromDistinctAscList [(k, v) | k <- S.toAscList s]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an observation: when looking up a set, it is sufficient to look up each of its elements and union those results together. I therefore propose that we keep two pieces of data: the insertions, and a mapping from elements to the sets that have those elements.

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Set as S

flatLookup :: Ord k => Map k (Set v) -> k -> [v]
flatLookup m k = maybe [] S.toList (M.lookup k m)

type SetMap k v = (Map (Set k) (Set v), Map k (Set (Set k)))

emptySM :: SetMap k v
emptySM = (M.empty, M.empty)

insertSM :: Ord k => Set k -> Set v -> SetMap k v -> SetMap k v
insertSM keys values (setMap, elemMap) = (setMap', elemMap') where
    setMap'  = M.insert keys values setMap
    newElems = M.fromList [(k, S.singleton keys) | k <- S.toList keys]
    elemMap' = M.unionWith S.union elemMap newElems

lookupSM :: (Ord k, Ord v) => Set k -> SetMap k v -> Set v
lookupSM keys (setMap, elemMap) = S.fromList $
    S.toList keys >>= flatLookup elemMap >>= flatLookup setMap

deleteSM :: Ord k => Set k -> SetMap k v -> SetMap k v
deleteSM keys (setMap, elemMap) = (setMap', elemMap') where
    setMap'  = M.delete keys setMap
    delElems = M.fromList [(k, S.singleton keys) | k <- S.toList keys]
    elemMap' = M.unionWith S.difference elemMap delElems
```

In ghci:

```
*Main> let x = insertSM (S.fromList [2,3]) (S.fromList [200]) . insertSM (S.fromList [1,2]) (S.fromList [100]) $ emptySM
*Main> lookupSM (S.fromList [2,3]) x
fromList [100,200]
```

So at least your test-case passes. =)

Insertion is pretty cheap. Suppose you've already inserted n keysets of average size m and the new set has size k. The expensive part is doing k insertions into the second map. Finding the right place to insert does O(log n) comparisons of sets of size m, so the top-level insertion takes O(km*log n) time.

Lookup is not terrible, either. Suppose you've already inserted n keysets of average size m. The expensive part is looking up the keysets that your keys participate in; in the worst case, we must look up all n keysets. This takes O(nm*log n) time total.

If you don't care about removing elements, this can be simplified significantly (and the complexity improved, as well):

```
type SetMap' k v = Map k (Set v)

emptySM' :: SetMap' k v
emptySM' = M.empty

insertSM' :: (Ord k, Ord v) => Set k -> Set v -> SetMap' k v -> SetMap' k v
insertSM' keys values setMap = M.unionWith S.union setMap newMap where
    newMap = M.fromList [(k, values) | k <- S.toList keys]

lookupSM' :: (Ord k, Ord v) => Set k -> SetMap' k v -> Set v
lookupSM' keys setMap = S.fromList $ S.toList keys >>= flatLookup setMap
```

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but you've coded it far more elegantly than I could (love that list monad)!  If you insert a large keyset, and then do a lookup with the same large keyset, then doesn't the outer `S.toList` have to do a lot of work discarding all of the duplicate copies of the valuesets?  I guess it's no worse than inserting the same large valueset under a large number of small keysets, and then doing a lookup with the union of all of those small keysets.

Comment: The `SetMap'` is vaguely like a bloom filter (in that it is not possible to delete elements).  However, if, instead of using `Set v` you used `Map v Int`, you could count the number of times each value had been inserted by a keyset containing `k`, and then you could implement delete.

Comment: @pat Cool, the `Map v Int` idea is really beautiful! I guess you'd still need the other half of the data structure in that case.

Comment: Thanks.  I implemented it in the solution below.  It's quite a bit uglier than I hoped.  Please feel free to tidy it up!

Comment: I'm not sure if your observation is correct. Consider `{1, 2} -> {100, 200}, {4, 5} -> {100, 300}`. Under your assumptions, `lookup {1, 5} = {100}`. I don't know what the OP wants, but in my reading of the spec, I'd imagine that lookup `{1, 5} = {}`?

Comment: The OP says that lookup is the union of the valuesets associated with every subset of the keyset.  So, given your example, `lookup {1, 5} = {100, 200, 300}`

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so you are saying that when you insert a set into this map, all the subsets of the set get mapped as well.

You have analyzed that the insertion complexity, if you use a `Data.Map`, is *O(2^n)* where `n` is the size of the set of the set to insert. That's about right, it's actually *O(n 2^n)* because insertion is *O(log n)*.

Therefore, if you want to avoid exponential time, you can't take this route. Inserting all the subsets when you insert a set will be exponential time.  So we have to figure something else out.  What sorts of operations do you need on the map?  I will assume that you just need lookup: i.e. find the value assigned to a given set. The choice of solution is always dependent on both you insertion and your lookup interface.

Other things to consider: is it okay if insertion is more expensive than lookup? Or the other way around? What are the usage patterns?

So we have two operations (I will call the type we are designing `SetMap`).  Also note that all this code will be pseudocode: there will probably be some class constraints on the variables, and I'm assuming the existence of functions whose semantics correspond to their names.

```
insert :: Set a -> b -> SetMap a b -> SetMap a b
lookup :: SetMap a b -> Set a -> Maybe b
```

We could implement `SetMap a b = [(Set a, b)]`, and then insertion would be *O(1)* and lookup would be *O(n m)* (where *n* is the number of items inserted and *m* is the size of the key being looked up). Not great, obviously.

What if you organized the sets in the map in a tree by unions.

```
data SetMap a b
    = Branch (Set a) [SetMap a b]
    | Leaf b
```

So, for example, the root of the tree would be the union of every key in the map. Then to lookup a key in the map you see if the key is a subset of the root; if so, then you try to lookup the key in each of its children, otherwise you fail:

```
lookup :: SetMap a b -> Set a -> Maybe b
lookup (Branch s children) x
    | x `subset` s = msum $ map (`lookup` x) children
    | otherwise    = Nothing
lookup (Leaf b) x = Just b
```

I am not quite sure how to analyze the complexity of this data structure, it kind of depends on the shape of your sets.

I'm sure there are other options, that's the first thing that came to mind. I'd be happy to help more on this problem (perhaps on a new SO question), but could you describe what you are doing in more detail? It's hard to tell the constraints of your problem from your limited description. Don't be shy, describe your goal in practical terms; a lot of times I reduce my problems to the need for a certain data structure, when the best solution comes from taking a step back and re-expressing the problem so I don't need that data structure.

Comment: I think the values (type `b` in the signatures) should themselves be sets.

Comment: @pat, by my understanding of the problem, there is no need. You can instantiate the type variable `b` with `Set c` if you like; `SetMap' a b = SetMap a (Set b)`, so this way is more general.

However, that comment made me see another interpretation of the problem. Perhaps `lookup` returns the *union* of all the values that were set for that key. There might be a way to use that to our advantage when designing the data structure, and hadn't considered that possibility.  (However in that case, we might as well generalize from Set to an arbitrary monoid)

Comment: Yes, I implicitly meant that `lookup` was supposed to return the union of the values.  I see the misunderstanding :-) thx